# Can someone explain the highlighted code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

So I was trying this exercise titled "Int to Roman Numerals" I found online. And I could not figure it out. The question stated, "Write a Python program to convert an integer to a roman numeral." After looking at the solution, I understood most of it. I just did not understand the parts I have put a comment next to. If someone can explain the logic, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
class py_solution:
    def int_to_Roman(self, num):

        val = [
            1000, 900, 500, 400,
            100, 90, 50, 40,
            10, 9, 5, 4,
            1
            ]

        syb = [
            "M", "CM", "D", "CD",
            "C", "XC", "L", "XL",
            "X", "IX", "V", "IV",
            "I"
            ]

        roman_num = ''
        i = 0
        while  num > 0:
             for _ in range(num // val[i]): # what does this line do?
                 roman_num += syb[i] # what does this line do?
             num -= val[i] # what does this line do?
        i += 1
    return roman_num
```

Comment: Check [Python operators](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp)

Comment: The `for _ in range(num // val[i])` executes the code in the `for` loop a `num // val[i]` number of times. The `roman_num += syb[i]` is shorthand for `roman_num = roman_num + syb[i]`. The next line does something similar only it's subtracts the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`num // val[i]` will do floor division of `num` by `val[i]`. For example:

```
>>> 5 // 2
2
```

Putting it in `range()` means it will create an iterator from 0 to that number. So in the above example, it would iterate over the numbers `0, 1` (the last number is not included, and we start at 0).

`roman_num += syb[i]` will concatinate `syb[i]` to `roman_num` and assign the result to `roman_num`. So if `roman_num` were `XII` and `syb[i]` were `I`, `roman_num` would now be `XIII`. You use '+' either to concatenate (join) strings, or to add numbers.

`num -= val[i]` will take the value of `num`, decrement it by `val[i]` and then assign the result to `num`. So if `num` were 5 and `val[i]` were 1, `num` would become 4.

Answer (score 0):

In python "//" operator call as floor division. This means first and second values will be divided and result will floored (15 // 2 = 7). Therefore in code, it will divide the number to val[indexNo] and will take the nearest whole number. And after that it will add into roman_num variable. And of course, it should extract the current value from num variable. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

To explain the while and for loop I have put some comments below. The idea is to keep subtracting away specific integer numbers from the `val` list from the input number `num`, until eventually the input number is zero. During each subtraction, the proper roman character is added to the output string. Recall that a roman number is written as a sum of integer numbers. (Note that the expression `a+=1` is equivalent to `a=a+1` in python, similarly  `a-=1`, is equivalent to `a=a-1`. Also note that `range(num // val[i])` is a list of integer numbers, for instance `range(3)` is equivalent to `[0,1,2]`. The operator `a//b` is floor division and returns a/b clipping away the decimals.)

```
roman_num = '' # Create an empty string to contain the resulting roman character
i = 0 # set iteration count to zero
while  num > 0: # while the input number has not been fully converted to roman
# loop now for as many times as the number can be 
# divided with val[i] without producing a decimal rest
# (the character _ could be arbitrarily replaced)
    for _ in range(num // val[i]): 
        roman_num += syb[i] # add roman character corresponding to val[i]
        num -= val[i] # subtract val[i] from the input number
    i += 1 # go to the next number in the val list by incrementing the counter
```